# Running R in-database SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, r, azure

Seeking advice about running R in-database SQL 2016 for a multi-user application — what is the best way to manage the task of multiple users running user jobs in parallel?

Comment: *Have* you checked the tutorials and documentation? The documentation answers all of your questions - the prerequisites for installing R Services, integrating with SQL Server, executing scripts, installing and upgrading packages, installing a separate R Server